# "Unrecognized Selector Error" While Using Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

I receive the following error when tapping on a view:

```
2015-08-04 15:42:16.236 jake-and-bailey[12158:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainMenuViewController openSettingsPage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7af560f0'
```

I added the following gesture recognizer to that view:

**Interface:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OpenSettingsGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer

@property UIViewController* viewController;

- (instancetype) initWithViewController: (UIViewController*) viewController;

@end
```

**Implementation:**

```
#import "OpenSettingsGestureRecognizer.h"
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

@implementation OpenSettingsGestureRecognizer

- (instancetype) initWithViewController: (UIViewController*) viewController {
    self = [super initWithTarget:viewController
                          action:@selector(openSettingsPage)];
    if (self) {
        _viewController = viewController;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) openSettingsPage {
    if (_viewController != nil) {
        [_viewController presentViewController:[[SettingsViewController alloc] init]
                                      animated:YES
                                    completion:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

For whatever reason the method *openSettingsPage* is being called from my *MainMenuViewController* class rather than the *OpenSettingsGestureRecognizer* class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s target with whichever `UIViewController` you're using to initialize its `OpenSettingsGestureRecognizer` subclass. Try changing:

```
self = [super initWithTarget:viewController
                      action:@selector(openSettingsPage)];
```

to

```
self = [super initWithTarget:self
                      action:@selector(openSettingsPage)];
```

if you want the target to be `OpenSettingsGestureRecognizer` instead of `MainMenuViewController` (which I assume this the `UIViewController` you're using to initialize the gesture).

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Change the target to `self` and you're good to go like so:

```
 self = [super initWithTarget:self
                          action:@selector(openSettingsPage)];
```

Read about target-action design pattern [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer!